# Modify initial object values in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a code what take the next array:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        name:'',
        age:55
    },
    {
        name:'Bill',
        age:''
    },
]
```

..and i should take into account, if the key does not contains a value, i should output for that key, the value: `no data`;

 At the end i shoul get something like this:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        name:'no data',
        age:55
    },
    {
        name:'Bill',
        age:'no data'
    },
]
```

I made this:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        name:'',
        age:55
    },
    {
        name:'Bill',
        age:''
    },
]
const func = (arr) => {
const myKeys = arr.map(k => Object.keys(k))
   return  arr.map((i, k1) => {
        return myKeys[k1].reduce((acc,r )=> {
            return {
                [acc] : !i[r].toString().length ? 'no data' :i[r] 
            }
        })
       
    })
};
console.log(func(arr))
```

How to achieve what i described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understood your question, but this seems to work:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        name:'',
        age:55
    },
    {
        name:'Bill',
        age:''
    },
]

arr.forEach(item => {
  for(let key in item) {
    if(!item[key]) item[key] = 'no data';
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries from the object, check the value and build a new object.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'no data', age: 55 }, { name: 'Bill', age: 'no data' }],
    result = array.map(o => 
        Object.fromEntries(Object
            .entries(o)
            .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.toString() ? v : 'no data'])
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: could you take a  look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047692/the-data-is-not-rendered-in-html/63048230#63048230

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a double `forEach`:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        name:'',
        age:55
    },
    {
        name:'Bill',
        age:''
    },
]
const func = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach((el) => {
    Object.keys(el).forEach((k) => el[k] = el[k].toString().length ? el[k] : 'no data')
  });
  return arr;
};
console.log(func(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the accumulator correctly in the `reduce` function. `acc` is the object you're building, not a property name. `r` is the current property name. So you should be assigning to `acc[r]`.

You also need to provide an initial value argument `{}`.

You can also simplify the code by just calling `Object.keys()` inside the `map` function, rather than making a separate array of all the keys.

```js
const arr = [{
    name: '',
    age: 55
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    age: ''
  },
]
const func = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((i) => {
    return Object.keys(i).reduce((acc, r) => {
      acc[r] = !i[r].toString().length ? 'no data' : i[r];
      return acc;
    }, {})

  })
};
console.log(func(arr))
```

Comment: could you take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047692/the-data-is-not-rendered-in-html/63048230#63048230

Answer (score 0):

you can loop throw array object using map() then loop again throw object and see if object entry has value or not

```
arr.map(ele=>  {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(ele)) {
        ele[key] = value ? value : 'no data';
    }
})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it