# The data is not rendered in html

Tags: javascript

I create a class what is responsible to output a search value.

```js
function templateHtml( results = []) {
    const items = results.map(item => {
        console.log(`<li>${item.name}</li>`)

        return `
                <li>${item.name}</li>
                `
    });

    return `
         <div class="search__bar">
                <input id="search__input" type="text" placeholder="type ">
            </div>
            <div class="search__results">
                <ul>
                
                    ${console.log(items.join("").trim())}
                    ${items.join(" ")}
                </ul>
            </div>
    `
}

class Search {
    constructor( selector, input, data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.selector = document.querySelector(selector);
        this.#render();
        this.input = document.querySelector(input);
        this.type()
    }

    #render() {
        this.selector.innerHTML = templateHtml();
    }


    type() {
        this.input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            const r = this.data.filter(data => data.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
            console.log(r)

            templateHtml(r)
            if (r.length) {
                this.show()
            } else {
                this.hide()
            }
        })
    }
}

const data = [
    {
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        name: "Carl"
    },
];


const search = new Search( '#search', '#search__input', data);
```

```html
  <div class="container">
        <div id="search">

        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue is that the searched value from input is not rendered in the html:

```js
return `
   <li>${item.name}</li>
  `
```

Why i get undefined in html template instead of the value? Or there i get the right value in `console.log(<li>${item.name}</li>)`.

Comment: What is `this.placeholder` referring to? I don't see it declared anywhere

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, i removed now that piece of code. I forgot do delete it when i write the question.

Comment: Also, you have a random curly bracket: `placeholder="type "}>`

Comment: So if you're not passing it any arguments, `results` is empty

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, yes, `results` is empty only before typing something, but when i type `carl` for example in result appears the value but not in html template.

Comment: `templateHtml('search', r)` what is the 'search' for?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, there i forgot to remove all code related to placeholder. In the past i sent the placeholder name as the first parameter. Now i removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218407/discussion-between-askmen-and-daniel-knights).

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, do you have an idea why i get undefined in html?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're after but I've refactored your code a bit:

```js
function templateHtml(results) {
  if (results)
    items = [];

  results.forEach(item => {
    const li = `<li>${item.name}</li>`;
    items.push(li)
  });

  const ul = `<ul>${items.join("")}</ul>`
  console.log(ul)

  document.getElementById('search__list').innerHTML = ul;
}

class Search {
  constructor(selector, input, data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.selector = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.input = document.querySelector(input);
    this.type()
  }

  type() {
    if (this.input)
      this.input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const r = this.data.filter(data => data.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
        console.log(r)

        templateHtml(r)
      })
  }
}

const data = [
  {
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    name: "john"
  },
  {
    name: "Carl"
  },
];


const search = new Search('#search', '#search__input', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="search">
    <div class="search__bar">
      <input id="search__input" type="text" placeholder="type ">
    </div>
    <div class="search__results" id="search__list"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically just using a `forEach` loop to populate a `ul` element and then setting it inside the `search__list` div.

Comment: but why in my example the code does not work? I can't figure out why i get undefined there. Do you now?

Comment: You get `undefined` because of `${console.log(items.join("").trim())}`

Comment: And the HTML isn't being altered because you aren't re-rendering anything after the page has loaded

Comment: How can i re-render when i type something in the input to make my code working?

Comment: You could use your render function but you'd have to hard code a selector for it to work. Or you could make another function outside of the class which resets the `innerHTML` of the search div, then inside your event listener do `newRenderFunction(templateHtml(r))`. I think that'd work, you'd have to test it out though